# Parse-server questionable security of masterkey

Tags: parse-server

I ma using parse instead of Firebase, for obvious reasons and I was wondering how I can secure my code.
As the masterkey and ID are both present on the client side and can easily be extracted and misused. How can I secure my application further and don't let the client have access to the key ?

Comment: only thing req'd on the client is an app-id <if u are on the rest api>. Unlike the MstrKey, the app-id  which is kinda like a token and not that big a deal

Comment: Still with the client key, the user can edit and update and remove a lot, is there anyway to secure this someway somehow ?

Comment: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/3636   some more links if u want more info on the issue

Comment: @Hypothesis - client actions are constrained by class level permission and ACLs.

Answer (score 1):

Your master key shouldn't be getting sent client side, only server side, per [the parse-server documentation](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#configuration):

> masterKey (required) - The master key to use for overriding ACL security. You can use any arbitrary string. Keep it secret! For migrated apps, this should match your hosted Parse app.

and also [here](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/413):

> - Only use it on the server; distributing the master key to your client means anyone can edit your data
> - To use it, it needs to be provided at initialization: Parse.initialize(applicationKey, optionalJSKey, masterKey);
> - To use it for all requests, call Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()
> - To use it for a single request, provide useMasterKey: true in the optional permissions object passed as the final parameter to any server call, eg: myObject.save({}, {useMasterKey: true})

What are you using the master key for on your client side? There may be another way to accomplish the task.

Edit: According to [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/) the second argument to initialize() is the javascript key, not the master key. Have you tried configuring your javascript key on the server side and using that instead?

Edit 2: [Use access control lists](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#security-for-other-objects) to limit client side access to your server data.

Comment: without Parse.initialize("myapp1", "thisismymasterkey") I can't connect and use Parse

Comment: @Hypothesis the Parse.initialize call should take the appId and the clientKey as arguments not the masterKey.

Comment: Still with the client key, the user can edit and update and remove a lot, is there anyway to secure this someway somehow ?

Comment: You use ACL and class level permissions, as described in the documentation

Comment: @flovilmart is the client_key defined on the server or just something we define on the client/app side ?